# Django + Emacs (as TextMate replacement)

Tags: django, emacs, textmate

There is any complete tutorial how to configure emacs for using with Django (1.1) (on Mac)?
Im thinking about switch from TextMate to Emacs to have multiplatform editor for django. I have my fav. theme from textmate and I want to convert this to emacs (maybe is "converter" for this?). Switching from Textmate is a good idea ?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I second @docgnome's suggestion of [Django mode](http://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/Emacs) and [yasnippet](http://code.google.com/p/yasnippet/), but the real kicker that will make you never want to go back to TextMate is to integrate [PyFlakes](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyflakes) into your development environment, at which point Emacs will provide you on-the-fly notification of errors in your Python code.  These go far beyond the typo-level error detection you get for free merely by having syntax highlighting; you'll be notified of errors such as variable before assignment, unused imports, and bad indentation, among other things.

Installing PyFlakes in Emacs is relatively straightforward: just download and install [PyFlakes](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyflakes), and then add the following to your `~/.emacs` or `~/.emacs.d/init.el`, as appropriate:

```
(when (load "flymake" t) 
  (defun flymake-pyflakes-init () 
    (let* ((temp-file (flymake-init-create-temp-buffer-copy 
                       'flymake-create-temp-inplace)) 
           (local-file (file-relative-name 
                        temp-file 
                        (file-name-directory buffer-file-name)))) 
      (list "pyflakes" (list local-file)))) 
  (add-to-list 'flymake-allowed-file-name-masks 
               '("\\.py\\'" flymake-pyflakes-init)))
(add-hook 'python-mode-hook 'flymake-mode)
```

That's it.  You should now notice that, whenever you're editing Python, errors are highlighted in red.  Mouse over to see a full explanation of what's wrong with the provided line.

As far as theming like TextMate: theming can be a bit annoying Emacs; unless you truly want the exact theme you have in TextMate, I'd grab [Color Theme](http://www.nongnu.org/color-theme/) for Emacs and find one that suits your fancy.  You can almost certainly find one very close to your current TextMate one, and won't have to deal with manually configuring faces.

Comment: I'd also recommend Emacs Starter Kit for anyone coming from a Mac background.  It's a very sane set of defaults.

Answer (score 4):

You might check out [Django mode for emacs](http://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/Emacs). What specific functionality were you looking for? For snippets, I recommend [yasnippet](http://code.google.com/p/yasnippet/) which is inspired by the TextMate snippet system.

Comment: how do you use the snippets after installing yasnippet? In Sublime Text it's pretty straight forward, you type "if", then it shows you a list of what snippets are available, then you can press TAB and it will write {% if rze = rze %} for you. Then you can go through each element and edit them with TAB